# Js return the start date and end date on a string

Tags: javascript, string, date

I have strings like this:

```
(Feb 28-Mar 1)
(Mar 2-3)
```

I would like me to return an object as you can see below, someone to give some suggestion how can I do?

```js
    function rD(text){
    let date = text.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(' ');
    //const [start, end] = date[2].split("-").map(Number);
    return date;
    }
    
    
    console.log(rD("(Feb 28-Mar 1)"))
    console.log(rD("(Mar 2-3)"))
```

Return:

```
[
{
  month: 2,
  day: 28
},
{
  month: 3,
  day: 1
}
]

[
{
  month: 3,
  day: 2
},
{
  month: 3,
  day: 3
}
]
```

Comment: It is not clear what your input and output is and what you need to do

Comment: @Paul I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd remove the parentheses first and then split by `/[ -]/`. This way you get an array in one of these two forms

```
["Feb", "28", "Mar", "1"]
```

or

```
["Mar", "2", "3"]
```

Now if the array has 4 elements the first and third are always the month and second and forth are the day. If the array has 3 elements, the first is a month for both, start and end, the second and third are the days.

For getting the number of the month you can have a simple lookup like

```
{ Jan:1, Feb:2, ... }
```

```js
let months = { Jan: 1, Feb: 2, Mar: 3 /*  you get the idea*/}
let spans = ["(Jan 28 - Feb 3)", "(Mar 1-3)"]

let parse = (span) => {
  let parts = span.replace(/[()]/g, "").split(/[ -]/).filter(x => !!x);
  switch (parts.length) {
    case 4: return [{month: months[parts[0]], date: +parts[1]}, {month: months[parts[2]], date: +parts[3]}];
    case 3: return [{month: months[parts[0]], date: +parts[1]}, {month: months[parts[0]], date: +parts[2]}];
    default: return undefined;
  }
}


console.log(parse(spans[0]));
console.log(parse(spans[1]))
```

Comment: You don't need the filter if you change the split regex simply to `/ ?\- ?/`. Also it's good practice to escape that dash.

Comment: @code that regex you proposed for the split means something completely different and won't work with my approach. Mine splits by any of `" "` and `"-"`, ie it will also split up `"Feb 28"`. Your's won't do that, it will just split by `"-"` optionally with a leading or trailing space.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding. I thought you wanted to filter out just ` - ` or `-`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a regex pattern to parse each span.

From this we can get the startMonth, startDay, endMonth, endDay. We can then create a `getMonthNumber()` function to turn the abbreviated month name (Jan, Feb, etc.) to a number.

```js
function getMonthNumber(month) {
    const lookup = { jan: 01, feb: 02, mar: 03, apr: 04, may: 05, jun: 06, jul: 07, aug: 08, sep: 09, oct: 10, nov: 11, dec: 12};
    return lookup[(month + '').toLowerCase()]
}

function parseSpan(str) {
    const pattern = /\(([a-z]{3})\s+(\d{1,2})\-([a-z]{3})?\s?(\d{1,2})\)/i
    const [, startMonth, startDay, endMonth, endDay] = str.match(pattern);
    return [
        { month: getMonthNumber(startMonth), day: +startDay },
        { month: getMonthNumber(endMonth || startMonth), day: +endDay }
    ];
}

let testInputs = [
  '(Feb 28-Mar 1)',
  '(Mar 2-3)',
  '(Sep 28-Oct 31)',
  '(Jan 3-17)'
]

testInputs.map(parseSpan).forEach(span => console.log(span))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: What if the input is "Feb 12-13-Mar 2"? `Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

Comment: I'll add an update for that!

Comment: Great. If you wish you can check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71328327/15359157) as well. It's better though that your code throws an error while the other answers all silently return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
function rangeCalcFunc(range = null) {
  if(range && range.length){
    const [start, end] = range.substring(1, range.length-1).split("-");
    console.log(start);console.log(end);
    const [startMon, startDt] = start.split(" ");
    const [endMon, endDt] = end.split(" ");
    
    return [
    {
      month: calcMonthInNumber(startMon.trim()),
      date: startDt
    },
    {
      month: calcMonthInNumber(endMon.trim()),
      date: endDt
    }
    ]
  }
}

function calcMonthInNumber(month) {
    switch(month.toLowerCase()){
      case 'jan': return '01'
      case 'feb': return '02'
      //add for other months
      default: break;
    }
}

console.log(rangeCalcFunc("(Jan 28-Feb 1)"));
```

Comment: That won't work on an input like `"Mar 2-3"`

Comment: yeah I missed that usecase.. will edit

Answer (score 1):

First we are going to create a mapper for the months. like this:

```
let MonthsMapper = new Map([['Jan', 1], ['Feb', 2], ['Mar', 3] /*...*/])
```

Then we need a function which cutes the string into chunks by removing the parenthesis and splitting it by its hyphen.
The first chunks are the start and end dates.
With these two dates we can further get the start month, start day, end month, and end day. (By splitting our chunks by there whitespaces)

There is only one special case I can see from your example and that is the case when the end date does not specify a month, in which case it is implicitly the start month.

```
let DateObjectParser = (dateString) => {
    const [startDate, endDate] = dateString.replace(/[()]/g, '').split('-')
    const [startMonth, startDay] = startDate.split(' ')
    let [endMonth, endDay] = endDate.split(' ')

    // in case a second month is not provided
    if (endDay === undefined) {
        endDay = endMonth
        endMonth = startMonth
    }

    return [
       {
           month: MonthsMapper.get(startMonth),
           day: parseInt(startDay),
       },
       {
            month: MonthsMapper.get(endMonth),
            day: parseInt(endDay),
       }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @derpirscher I copy-pasted it into my console. With the input "DateObjectParser("(Mar 2-3)")" the output is "[{month: 3, day: 2}, {month: 3, day: 3}]" as I would expect it. Would you mind to elaborate on what would not work?

Comment: Ah sorry, missed the extra handling of the missing second month ...

Comment: Instead of a map couldn't you just use a regular object?

Comment: @code Indeed, a regular object would have also been perfectly fine. But since we have in this specific example a "mapper", I thought it would be the best to use a Map instead of a regular object. (+Readibility)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the code, the advantage to this approach is that it works if the input is something like `Jan 1-3-Mar 7`, while all the other answers don't put this into consideration, thus returning `undefined` or an error.

Simple regex and a list of month to numbers should work, and it seems the most straightforward to me. Using `String.prototype.match` we can "ignore" all the extra data (i.e. the parentheses and dashes between months), just extract the necessary data:

```js
function rD(str) {
  // have a list of the numbers of each month
  const monthNum = {
    jan: 1,
    feb: 2,
    mar: 3,
    apr: 4,
    may: 5,
    jun: 6,
    jul: 7,
    aug: 8,
    sep: 9,
    oct: 10,
    nov: 11,
    dec: 12
  };

  // regex to extract the patterns "Feb 23" or "Aug 15-23"
  let spl = str.match(/[a-z]{3} \d{1,2}(\-\d{1,2})?/gi);

  // loop through matches
  const result = spl.map(s => {
    // first 3 letters is the month; get the month number
    const month = monthNum[s.substr(0, 3).toLowerCase()],
      rest = s.substr(4); // get the rest of the string sans the month and extra space
    const e = rest.split("-");
    return e.map(q => ({
      month,
      day: +q
    }));
  }).flat(); // our array may occasionally be multidimensional if the user provides something like "Nov 7-12". We flatten the array to fix that
  return result;
}

console.log("(Feb 28-Mar 1):", rD("(Feb 28-Mar 1)"));
console.log("(Mar 2-3):", rD("(Mar 2-3)"));
console.log("(Nov 7-12-Dec 15):", rD("(Nov 7-12-Dec 15)"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: What advantage is it to take something into consideration that wasn't even in the specifications? And thus making the whole approach more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: And if you are already working with regex, you should probably make use of capture groups, so you won't need to `.substr()` or `.split()` your matches anymore ...

Comment: @derpirscher I don't know about you, but to me that seems *implied* in the OP's specifications. Also, why regex everything up when you don't need to? I'm not overusing or stretching the use of these string methods.

Comment: To me "start" and "end" seems pretty much indicate two dates and not three, also the examples only showed two dates. You don't have to "*regex everything up*", but if you're already validating the correct format with an regex, why not utilize it also to extract the parts you already validated anyways instead of going over the string again twice for split and substring?

Comment: @derpirscher I don't understand. If you put all the data processing into a single regex and match it will only complicate everything up. Please, the conversation is going nowhere. It really isn't that important whether to use string methods versus a single regex.

Answer (score 0):

Added all the steps inline in below code snippet.

```js
// const str = "(Feb 28-Mar 1)";
const str = "(Mar 2-3)";

// An Object which contains numeric value of months.
const monthMap = {
  Jan: 1,
  Feb: 2,
  Mar: 3
};

/**
 * convertStringToObject() method used to convert the input string into an object.
 * @param : inputString
 */
function convertStringToObject(inputString) {
  // Removing open and closed paranthesis and splitting the inputString with '-'
    const split = inputString.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split('-');
  // If splitted array element does not contain month, appending that. 
  split[1] = (split[1].trim().length === 1) ? split[0].split(' ')[0] + ' ' + split[1] : split[1];
  // Looping over the splitted array and then creating the object with keys 'month' and 'day'
  return split.map((item) => {
    const splittedItem = item.split(' ');
    return {
        month: monthMap[splittedItem[0]],
      day: Number(splittedItem[1])
    }
  });
}

// Calling the convertStringToObject() method by passing the input string as a param.
console.log(convertStringToObject(str));
```